# Apache mod_proxy and icap protocol

Tags: apache, proxy, icap

I try to use Apache mod_proxy for icap protocol.

My configurations looks like:

```
<Location /RESPMOD>
    ProxyPass icap://IP:1344/RESPMOD?policy=virus_only
    ProxyPassReverse icap://IP:1344/RESPMOD?policy=virus_only

    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Location>
```

The proxy module is built-in.

But than I get

```
[warn] proxy: No protocol handler was valid for the URL /RESPMOD. If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.
```

I didn't find proxy module for icap. Is there one (like for http protocol?) or should the configuration be different?

Answer (score 1):

Unluckily, there is no such module.